# $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are same irreducible, positive recurent, aperiodic markov chian and are independent. Is $(X_n,Y_n)$ positive recurrent?

Tags: stochastic-processes

Let $X_n,n \geq0$ be an irreducible, positive recurrent, aperiodic markov chain with state space $S$ and transition matrix $P$. $Y_n$ has the same $S$ and $P$ but independent with $X_n$. Then $\epsilon=(X_n,Y_n)$ becomes a new markov chian with state spacde $S \times S$. My question is $\epsilon$ recurrent or positive recurrent?

It's obvious $\epsilon$ is irreducible. I do some research on it and can not figure this out... Only know this kind is called "coupled markov chain"... Any hint? Thank you!

Comment: Are you assuming a finite or countably infinite state space $S$?  If so, then "yes" because you can find a probability vector that satisfies the global balance equations. That vector is just a multiplication of the individual steady state vectors. That is $\pi(i,j) = \pi(i)\pi(j)$.

Comment: Another way to argue is that you know, for all states $i$ and $j$ and all initial conditions $x_0,y_0$, we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P[X_n=i|X_0=x_0] = \pi(i)>0$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P[Y_n=j|Y_0=y_0]=\pi(j)>0$, and by independence $P[X_n=i,Y_n=j|X_0=x_0,Y_0=y_0]=P[X_n=i|X_0=x_0]P[Y_n=j|Y_0=y_0]\rightarrow \pi(i)\pi(j)>0$.

Comment: Yes, I do assume it's a coutably infinite state. but..sorry, I am a beginner on stochastic process. I have trouble getting you. Your first comment shows we have a stationary state, How can we know it's reccurent from this? The second shows we have positve elements for transition matrix. I cannot get why it's recurrent either.... Thanks a lot!

Comment: What tools do you have that you are comfortable using?  Specifically, can you assume you have the steady state theorem available?  Or, are you trying to _prove_ the steady state theorem?  You are using language of "irreducible" and "aperiodic" so I assumed you knew the steady state theorem.

Comment: Sure! I will learn the steady state theorem. Thanks a lot!